# ajax post and get coldfusion file. Get is failing after setting a value

Tags: jquery, ajax, coldfusion, stripe-payments, cfml

I am trying to write a stripe checkout component on my site. This uses a 'pay what you like' option so I need a way to send data for the total value via ajax.

```
const url = '/shop/api/test.cfm';
const sendCheckoutData = () => {
    const data = {};
    data.total = $('.total').val() * 100;
    console.log(data);
    if(!isNaN(data.total)) {
        $.ajax({
            url,
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success(data) {
                console.log('checkoutData sent');
                returnCheckoutData();
            },
            error(status) {
                console.log('checkoutData not sent', status.statusText);
            }
        });
    }
}
const returnCheckoutData = () => {
    $.ajax({
        url,
        type: 'GET',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success(data) {
            console.log('checkoutData returned');
        },
        error(status) {
            console.log('checkoutData not returned', status.statusText);
        }
    });
}
```

And in my cfm file I have the following:

```
<cfset requestBody = toString( getHttpRequestData().content ) />
<!--- Double-check to make sure it's a JSON value. --->
<cfif isJSON( requestBody )>
    <cfset VARIABLES.checkoutData = deserializeJSON( requestBody )>
</cfif>

<cfscript>
    secretKey = "MY_SECRET_KEY";
    crlf = chr(13)&chr(10);
    headers = "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"&crlf;
    headers &= "Authorization: Bearer "&secretKey&crlf;
    body = "success_url="&URLEncodedFormat("https://slackwise.org.uk/shop/checkout/complete.cfm")
                &"&cancel_url="&URLEncodedFormat("https://slackwise.org.uk/shop/checkout/fail.cfm")
                &"&payment_method_types[]=card"
                &"&line_items[0][amount]=#VARIABLES.checkoutData.total#"
                &"&line_items[0][currency]=gbp"
                &"&line_items[0][quantity]=1"
                &"&line_items[0][name]=widget";
</cfscript>

<cfx_http5 out="http5" method="post" url="https://api.stripe.com/v1/checkout/sessions" headers="#headers#" body="#body#" ssl="5">

<cfdump var="#deserializeJSON(http5)#">
```

On the post request it looks as though `VARIABLES.checkoutData` is being set to the correct amount and it is being passed to the `&line_items[0][amount]` in the body.
On ajax post success I want to do a get request to return the new values and generate a stripe token, and this is failing.

I get the following debug

`Message: Element CHECKOUTDATA.TOTAL is undefined in VARIABLES.`

I am not sure if the var is being reset.

I've also tried creating a cfc and wrapping my requestBody function inside the component, as well as the whole function (with the cfx_http5 call).

I am not 100% sure if the contentType is correct for the get request, what is the default contentType for a cfm file? I've tried removing it, and setting it to multipart/form-data, but possibly my approach is incorrect.

Any help much appreciated.

**EDIT**

Post request cfdump

```
struct
allow_promotion_codes   null
amount_subtotal 2400
amount_total    2400
billing_address_collection  null
cancel_url  https://slackwise.org.uk/shop/checkout/fail.cfm
client_reference_id null
currency    gbp
customer    null
customer_email  null
display_items   
array
1   
struct
amount  2400
currency    gbp
custom  
struct
description null
images  null
name    widget
quantity    1
type    custom
id  cs_test_removed
livemode    NO
locale  null
metadata    
struct [empty]
mode    payment
object  checkout.session
payment_intent  pi_1HSjSJIMlFPwHnRlo3DnfC0N
payment_method_types    
array
1   card
payment_status  unpaid
setup_intent    null
shipping    null
shipping_address_collection null
submit_type null
subscription    null
success_url https://slackwise.org.uk/shop/checkout/complete.cfm
total_details   
struct
amount_discount 0
amount_tax  0
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not really familiar with COldFusion, but this sppears to be a problem with how to manage ajax requests & data, rather than an issue with Stripe. If, for example, you try setting a hard-coded amount for checkout, does everything work as intended? If I were building this app with other tools, I'd create the Checkout session within the POST request and respond with the session id directly, instead of making a second GET request. Can you do that in CF?

Comment: Can you post the dumped requestBody - Minus any secret key?

Comment: Hey, I have added the cfdump from the post request (text and image) and just removed the ID. Maybe I don't need a get request. But data from this view needs to be sent to the stripe endpoint.

Comment: Is the error happening on `returnCheckoutData` call? If that is the case, you are not sending any JSON to that call (GET). Is there any reason you are trying to do the `returnCheckoutData` call to the same url?

Comment: @RRK yes error is being thrown from `returnCheckoutData`. In a previous project we would first send a post request in order to update data, and on success return a get to prove that the update had been successful, This seems like good practice to me. But I need someway to pass data from the BE cf call to the FE for the stripe gateway. I guess my cfm file is ALWAYS expecting a post request which is perhaps why it is not working.

Comment: Yes, there is no JSON in `returnCheckoutData ` call, because of that `VARIABLES.checkoutData` is not set and hence the error.